# sql after insertion trigger update column within the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insertion

im trying write a trigger to update a column in the same table when an insertion is done

my table is

```
create table BlueTooth (
ID int Primary Key NOT NULL ,
version varchar(45) NOT NULL,
score float null,
speed float 
);
```

my trigger is

```
create or replace trigger BlueToothsc
ON BlueTooth 
after insert 
as 
begin 
update BlueTooth set score((select speed from inserted)/(select max(speed) from BlueTooth ) * 100)
END 
GO
```

but i get errors in `"incorrect syntax near"  "or"` keyword in the first line 
and `"incorrect syntax near"  "as"`

can some one please help me with this

I want to update the `BlueTooth` tables `score` column by (inserted speed / max(speed) ) * 100)

when a faster version of bluetooth came in that should the the score value 100 and all the others should get a lower value respectively.

Comment: If `score` is meant to always be correct, this would surely better be calculated in a view, rather than stored in a table. I.e. if the first insert has a speed of `1`, and then a separate insert has a speed of `100`, then both scores will be 100. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right when i ran the trigger it will only change the inserted row and your example is correct that was not what i really wanted. i want to update all the score values  if a faster version of bluetooth comes dou you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of *storing* the score, prefer instead to calculate it at the point of query. So, in this case, a view should do the job:

```
create table BlueTooth (
ID int Primary Key NOT NULL ,
version varchar(45) NOT NULL,
speed float 
);
go
create view BlueToothScores
as
   select
       ID,
       version,
       speed,
       speed * 100 / MAX(speed) OVER () as score
   from
       BlueTooth
```

And now you don't need to worry about triggers or update routines - the results are always correct because they're calculated from the real data

Answer (score 1):

the syntax errors are

```
1) You have to create or alter the trigger seperately
2) missed = while assigning the value to score in update statement
```

Try this trigger.

```
create trigger BlueToothsc
ON BlueTooth 
after insert 
as 
begin 
update BlueTooth set score = ((select speed from inserted)/
             (select max(speed) from BlueTooth ) * 100)
where ID = (SELECT ID FROM INSERTED)
END 
GO
```

Comment: Will fail for any multi-row inserts, and updates the `score` for all rows in `Bluetooth` to the same value. The first is an error, and I'm fairly sure the second isn't what the OP is after.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever u r right i may need a procedure for this to update all the rows when i add a greater value